# Computação Paralela -como funciona a dependência de dados?

Tags: paralelismo

Estou estudando um pouco sobre computação paralela e estou com duvida de  como funciona a dependência de dados?

Comment: Eu sugiro que você tente incrementar melhor a pergunta, talvez colocando as referências do seu estudo e indicar o que exatamente você ficou em dúvida. Você entendeu o que é a dependência de dados, mas não entendeu como funciona? Ou nem entendeu o que é? Da maneira que está, ao meu ver, parece uma pergunta de lista de exercício de fixação e isso pode não ser muito bem recebido pela comunidade.